# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to type 'bool'

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting some legacy code from VB to C# and I am getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to type 'bool'.  An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)

on the `p2.Value = 1` in the if statement.

Here is the code in VB

```vb
Public Function CheckforRatingRemoval() As Boolean
    Dim param(2) As SqlParameter
    Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("@interviewID", SqlDbType.Int)
    p1.Value = _interviewID
    param(0) = p1
    Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("@flag", SqlDbType.Int)
    p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    param(1) = p2
    EDJOINControls.EdjoinDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery("usp_checkInterviewRatingRemoval", param)
    If p2.Value = 1 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Here it is converted to C#

```cs
public bool CheckforRatingRemoval()
{
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@interviewID", SqlDbType.Int);
    p1.Value = _interviewID;
    param[0] = p1;
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@flag", SqlDbType.Int);
    p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[1] = p2;
    EdjoinDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery("usp_checkInterviewRatingRemoval", param);
    if (p2.Value = 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably the legacy VB code had `Option Strict Off` making it automatically convert mismatching types. This does not happen for narrowing conversions in C#. `SqlParameter.Value` is of type `object`. Cast it to `int` explicitly.

```
return (int)p2.Value == 1;
```

The second problem is the use of `=`. In C# `=` is the assignment operator (which you don't want to use here) and `==` the equals operator.

Please, don't write

```
if ((int)p2.Value == 1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The result of the comparison `(int)p2.Value == 1` is either `true` or `false` and you can return this value directly! You don't write `if (x == 1) return 1; else if (x == 2) return 2; else if (x == 3) return 3; else ....`, you write `return x;`.

Btw.: there are several [online VB to C# converters](https://www.google.ch/search?q=VB%20to%20C%23%20converter) that can save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

In your Visual Basic code, the compiler is implicitly casting to the required type, so no compilation error. on the other hand, since you're performing an equality comparison of type `Object` (`p2.Value` returns a type `Object`) and an `int` thus `C#` requires you to cast it explicitly.
So, your code should be something along the lines of:

```
return (int)p2.Value == 1;
```

Also, note the use of the double equal operator for equality comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what got rid of the error

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(p2.Value) == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Consider replacing that with `return (Convert.ToInt32(p2.Value) == 1);`

Comment: You should be performing a cast, not a conversion, if the value of the parameter is already an `int`. A conversion is where you change the type of the object/value itself, whereas a cast is where you change the type of the variable/reference used to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

In C# an if statement basically simplifies down to `if (true)` or `if (false)`. The operator `==` returns true or false. The operator `=` sets a value. If you try to say `if (1 + 1 = 2)`, the program won't know what to do because it doesn't simplify down to a true or false so throws an error.

tl;dr use `==` instead of `=` in if statements.

Answer (score -1):

should it be

```
if (p2.Value == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

with double ==

Comment: @mjwills, bacuse in the `VB` in the  `if A = B`  `=` is equality operator, not assignment.

Comment: **I** know that, but the answer should say that.

Comment: i thought it was typo